# Печать слов, в предложении, с заглавной буквы

Tags: java

Объясните пожалуйста как работает код.

```
for (String word : s.split("\\b")) {
            System.out.print(word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Что именно вы не понимаете? Как работает foreach, или split, или substring?

Comment: split, и substring

Comment: Справка по этим функциям уже прочитана?

Comment: Да, все прочитано.Первым делом на Oracle.com

Comment: То есть когда вам по какой-то функции целая страница пояснений дана в документации -- вы из этого не понимаете, что делает эта функция, к когда написана одна строчка на so - вы вдруг резко прозреваете? Ну-ну. Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы: что именно вам не понятно было в документации, а не просто "документацию прочитал - НИ ОДНОГО слова не понял". Так не бывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для понятности разобью код на большее количество строк

```
String[] words = s.split("\\b");  \\ Разбиваем строку на массив слов
for (String word : words) {  \\ Обходим в цикле все элементы массива
    String firstLetter = word.substring(0, 1); \\ Получаем первую букву слова
    firstLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase(); \\ Приводим её к верхнему регистру
    String remainingLetters = word.substring(1); \\ Получаем все буквы слова со второй и до конца строки
    String capitalizedWord = firstLetter + remainingLetters; \\ Объединяем первую увеличенную букву с остальными, оставшимися неизменными
    System.out.print(capitalizedWord); \\ Выводим получившееся слова
}
```

[Описание метода split в документации.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)
[Описание метода substring в документации.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-)

Comment: Можно ещё про `\b` отдельно упомянуть

Comment: @DmitriiGolyshkin [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Regent см. например [Элементы языка регулярных выражений — краткий справочник](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) про "привязки".

Answer (score 1):

Метод split() возвращает массив строк, вычисленных путем разделения данной строки.
Например:

```
String s = "Какая-то-строка";
for (String x : s.split("-");
    System.out.println(x);
```

Результат:

Какая

то

строка

Метод subsring() создает новую строку, которая является подстрокой строки, для которой вызван substring(). Если вызвать substring( int n), где n индекс, с которого начинается подстрока, то подстрока будет состоять из всех символов после индекса n (включительно). Если вызвать substring(int n, int m), то подстрока будет состоять из символов от n (включительго), до m ( не включая).

Например:

```
String s = "hello";
s2 = s.substring(2);
s3 = s.substring(1, 4);
System.out.println(s2);
System.out.println(s3);
```

Вывод:

llo

ell